# Segfault accessing a (pointer) array in ctypes structure

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I'm trying to read a binary file with a given structure and place it in a ctypes struct like the following:

```py
class Dgm(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('header', Header),
                ('data_p', POINTER(Data))]
```

Where the **Data** type is:

```py
class Data(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('numSamples', c_uint16),
                ('samples_p', POINTER(c_int8))]
```

The goal is to extract **samples_p** from the file and return it as a bytearray. Notice that I've simplified the structs and they are much longer.

Now, to read the file I do the following:

```py
self.f.seek(self.__position - header.numBytes)
mwc = Dgm.from_buffer_copy(self.f.read(header.numBytes))
```

Then, to access the first element of the array:

```py
data = mwc.data_p[0]
```

Which returns `<Data object at HEX>` as one would expect. But if I try to read one of the elements in the struct I get a segfault:

```py
print(mwc.data_p[0].numSamples)
```

I've also tried to convert `mwc.data_p[i]` to a bytearray using `bytearray()` but I also get a segfault.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: You should post the code that fills the *struct*s.

Comment: I already posted it: `mwc = Dgm.from_buffer_copy(self.f.read(header.numBytes))`. The problem seemed to be that reading a file does not create proper pointers, so they have to be created manually pointing to some buffer.

Comment: You can't write a pointer to a file and read it back to get anything meaningful.  A pointer is just a memory address, not the actual byte array data.  The data in a binary file would have to be read into an appropriate array.

Comment: Describe your actual binary file structure (or at least a minimum version of it) and we can suggest ways to read it.

Comment: In the file, after the header, there are numSamples bytes. What I did to make it work (I don't know if it's the best approach) is keep a buffer of bytes as an attribute and then create the pointer manually to that buffer: `data.samples_p = (c_int8 * data.numSamples)(*samples)`.